# SwiftUI: Display ActionSheet once annotation is tapped

Tags: swift, swiftui, annotations, mapkit, mkannotation

I have created a `UIViewRepresantable` to display a map in SwiftUI. I want display an ActionSheet once the annotation is tapped. Inside the `Coordinator` I am trying to use the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method. Right now I am just trying to print "annotation is tapped" however this does not work. Anyone know what I might be missing?

---

```
struct MapModel: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let view = UIView()
    let map = MKMapView()
    
    let yedikuleShelter = ShelterAnnotation(title: "Yedikule Hayvan Barınağı", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.9907822322955, longitude: 28.920995484659933))
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        
        view.addSubview(map)
        
        map.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            map.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            map.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
            map.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            map.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
        
        return view
    }
    
    class MapViewCoordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var mapModelController: MapModel
        
        init(_ control: MapModel) {
            self.mapModelController = control
        }
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor
                        annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{
            let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "customView")
            //Custom Image Icon
            annotationView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "AnbulancePin")
            annotationView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
            return annotationView
        }
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
            let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            view.canShowCallout = true
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn 
        }
        
        //Display alert once annotation is tapped
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
            print("annotation is tapped")  
        }
        
    }
    
    class ShelterAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
        let title: String?
        let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
        init(title: String?,
             coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
            self.title = title
            self.coordinate = coordinate
        }
    }  
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.01224, longitude: 28.976018)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.7,
                                    longitudeDelta: 0.7)
        map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate,
                                         span: span),
                      animated: true)
        
        map.delegate = context.coordinator
        map.addAnnotation(yedikuleShelter)
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> MapViewCoordinator {
        MapViewCoordinator(self)
    }    
    
}
```

Comment: you have to Bind bool variable here and make it true in 'didSelect' function. Or you can take function type variable like let action: () -> Void and use it

Answer (score 0):

Your MapViewCoordinator was nested inside the MapModel.

```
struct MapModel: UIViewRepresentable {

  let view = UIView()
  let map = MKMapView()

  let yedikuleShelter = ShelterAnnotation(title: "Yedikule Hayvan Barınağı", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.9907822322955, longitude: 28.920995484659933))


  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
     view.addSubview(map)
    
     map.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        map.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
        map.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
        map.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        map.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        
     ])
    
     map.delegate = context.coordinator
    
     return view
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.01224, longitude: 28.976018)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.7,
                                longitudeDelta: 0.7)
    map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate,
                                     span: span),
                  animated: true)
    map.addAnnotation(yedikuleShelter)
  }

  func makeCoordinator() -> MapViewCoordinator {
    MapViewCoordinator()
  }
}


class MapViewCoordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {

  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor
                annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
     let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "customView")
    //Custom Image Icon
    annotationView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "AnbulancePin")
    annotationView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    return annotationView
  }

  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    view.canShowCallout = true
    view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
    print("Uday")
  }

  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    print("annotation is tapped")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @udbhateja for looking into this, however that did not fix the issue :/

Comment: You were unable to print "annotation is tapped", but here it's working fine